# Xubuntu - how to use both front and rear audio output?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, alsa, headphones

I have connected speakers to the back panel of my computer at work and I would like to have them always enabled (I can switch them off on the speaker casing). However when I connect headphones on the front panel system automatically says that the rear output is unplugged.

I found a solution to disable auto detection with Alsamixer and it works almost ok except the fact that after system restart I need to reconfigure the settings again... How can I set this once and forget about it?

Comment: what sound chipset do you have? output of `aplay -l`

Comment: `card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI]`, `card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH]` and `card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia]` but I need to adjust only volume of `PCH` in fact.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that changing the settings with `alsamixer` works fine. The issue I am experiencing is that the system forgets my changes on reboot so I need adjust speaker volume every morning... Maybe not much time but still: would prefer to keep these settings on restart. :)

Comment: The volume levels are stored in `~/.config/pulse/*device-volumes.tdb` You could backup that file in another directory after you have set your volume levels. Then restore that file at login.  It probably wouldn't hurt to back up all the files in  `~/.config/pulse/`

Comment: After files have been restored to `~/.config/pulse/` you will need to run `killall pulseaudio` for the changes to take affect. Pulseaudio will repawn.

Comment: So just do the config with `alsamixer`, zip `~/.config/pulse` and extract in `.bashrc`? Seems like a bit "brute force"... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74675/discussion-between-stumblebee-and-moby04).

Answer (score 7):

hdajackretask is a tool to reassign the function your jacks for different input, output or disabled - e g, turn your Mic jack into an extra Headphone, or why not make them both line outs and connect them to your surround receiver?

Install [alsa-tools-gui](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alsa-tools-gui&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Run `hdajackretask` Then To override one of your jacks:

1. Select a codec
2. Click the "Override" checkbox for that pin and select the new
   desired function
3. Test out the changes with the "Apply now" button
4. Once satisfied, click "Install Boot Override"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you disabling the `Auto-Mute Mode` in `AlsaMixer`?

```
amixer sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' 'Disabled'
```

does the same, you could add this to some startup script.