# The microphone is not recognized (Kubuntu)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, microphone

So I installed Kubuntu today (mic worked on Windows). The speakers work fine, but the mic doesn't and I think it is not even recognized.

[There is only one option for input audio, analog input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxRgO.png)

[Meanwhile I can either pick analog output or line out for output and line out gets the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5CvL.png)

Clearly Kubuntu doesn't recognize the mic. And since Windows did recognize it, I doubt the cause is mechanical. What should I try to solve the issue?

EDIT: I tried taking the speaker cable out and in and I got a signal while doing this, but I didnt get a signal while putting the microphone in the microphone input, but I get it if I put it in the speaker input.

EDIT2: Curiously, the microphone works if only the microphone is plugged in but not the speakers???

EDIT3:If I plug the microphone first, the microphone works and the speakers don't. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This is just so annoying, it would be stupid if I had to revert back to windows just due to this...

Answer (score 0):

I think (I also rebooted but I think I also rebooted before lol, would it be funny if just rebooting fixed it tho - I am now almost sure it made it work, I rebooted once when not applying the setting (was able only to use the mic, actually never the speakers), and the again applaying and it worked) this handy program located here [Xubuntu - how to use both front and rear audio output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013439/xubuntu-how-to-use-both-front-and-rear-audio-output) helped fix the issue.