# How do I repurpose audio ports on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, audio-jack

I have this problem where one of my audio ports is damaged (default front headphone) and on windows i have repurposed the front mic port for headphone input.

Now when I switch to linux I have no idea how to do the same thing. On Windows I used the Realtek panel.

EDIT to include system info.

aplay -l returns:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And pavucontrol shows only one device that doesn't output anything

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; but I'd first try `pavucontrol` (ie. *Pulse Audio Volume Control*) and see if was as simple as selecting another output port from the drop-down.  (*this should work too even if you're using a newer release using Pipewire - but you gave no specifics as to product & release*)

Comment: As guiverc asked, What version of Ubuntu are you using and also, what is the output of `aplay -l` Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1490521/edit) your question and include these details.

Comment: If you are using a HDA Intel sound chipset, I already have answered this question - [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013439/xubuntu-how-to-use-both-front-and-rear-audio-output/1015663#1015663)

Comment: @stumblebee I updated the question

Comment: Look at my previous comment and give it a try, There is a chance it may work. Select "Realtek ALC892" codec.

Comment: @stumblebee What do you mean by select?

Comment: In `hdajackretask` there is a pull down menu to select a codec as shown in my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013439/xubuntu-how-to-use-both-front-and-rear-audio-output/1015663#1015663)